# How to track errors when distributing Android Application to Alpha Testers?

Tags: android, debugging, testing

I recently released an application for some users to use my newly made `Android Application`. However, they are having trouble when they perform the `Facebook Login` feature that I have made.

It seems to work fine on my phone, but on other phones it seems to crash. I would like to know what is causing the application to crash so I can further debug this. Is there anywhere or anything that I can use to debug this problem further?

I have looked at both the `Facebook Developer Console` and `Google Play Developer Console` and neither seem to show or point me to where my error is. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: You should take a look at Firebase.

Comment: Can you show the `crash logcat`? It can also be related to [65k method limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605691/could-not-find-method-excpetion-noclassdeffounderror-for-external-library-bu)

Comment: @Carsten where can I look in Firebase?

Comment: @hrskrs how can I see the `crash logcat` for other users' phones though?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: @user1871869 user crashlytics, or any other tool then

Answer (score 2):

Use any Crashlytics/Analytics tools to not only get error logs but also usage statictics which can be pretty useful insight during pre-release tests. Some of them like Crashlytics by Fabric are even free and are very easy to integrate. But, there are many others too.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of cloud hosted solutions.These might be paid, and require signing up.

If you want to roll you own simple reporting mechanism, then there is an Android library: [ARCA](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) . You can set it up to send crash reports to an email address.

First, you'll need to include the library in app's `build.gradle` file:

```
compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.9.0'
```

Then declare extent the `Application` class (or modify if you already have) as :

```
import org.acra.*;
import org.acra.annotation.*;

@ReportsCrashes(mailTo = "reports@yourdomain.com",                
                mode = ReportingInteractionMode.TOAST,
                resToastText = R.string.crash_toast_text)
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);

        // The following line triggers the initialization of ACRA
        ACRA.init(this);
    }
}
```

The two thing necessary are:

1. Add `@ReportsCrashes` annotation to app's application class, with recipient mail address.
2. Override `attachBaseContext()` and include `ACRA.init()` in it.

Official docs:

1. [Setting up ARCA.](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup)
2. [Advanced configuration.](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/Report-Destinations#sending-reports-by-email)